# Long Permutations from Small Lists

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I have a list titled outcomes:

```
outcomes = ["heads", "tails"]
```

As you can see, the list has two elements.

If I want to get permutations from the list, I use the itertools python package as follows:

```
import itertools 

for permutation in itertools.permutations(outcomes, 2):
    print(permutation)
```

This code produces the following output:

```
('heads', 'tails')
('tails', 'heads')
```

The problem comes when I try to create permutations that are longer than my list; i.e. permutations with more than 2 elements. For instance if I try permutations of 3 or more elements, I get no output:

```
for permutation in itertools.permutations(outcomes, 3):
    print(permutation)
```

Are there any quick workarounds for this?

Comment: amost seems as if you were looking for `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`

Comment: Please show the output you want from the last code sample. By the definition of the word, a "permutation" of  `n` items has length `n`, containing each of the items exactly once. So you're not looking for a permutation - but without a concrete example, can't guess what you do want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `itertools.product`. A permutation is an ordering of the existing elements. What you're describing is really a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

```py
import itertools 

outcomes = ['heads', 'tails']
for flips in itertools.product(outcomes, repeat=3):
    print(flips)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a (maybe) less efficient (I think product also uses two for-loops) but (definitely) more verbose way to get the same outcome as itertools.product, which BrokenBenchmark has suggested, I have an alternative:

```
import itertools

outcomes = ["heads", "tails"]

combinations = [] 
for combination in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(outcomes,3):
    combinations.append(combination)

final = []
for combination in combinations:

    final = final + [*itertools.permutations(combination)]


print(list(set(final)))
```

(I did not know about itertools.product)

Output:

```
[('heads', 'heads', 'tails'), 
('heads', 'heads', 'heads'), 
('tails', 'tails', 'heads'), 
('tails', 'tails', 'tails'), 
('tails', 'heads', 'heads'), 
('tails', 'heads', 'tails'), 
('heads', 'tails', 'tails'), 
('heads', 'tails', 'heads')]
```